# Regex for getting alt attribute

Tags: php, html, regex, image

Is there any regex to get the alt attribute?
Example: `<img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/a61df59863ed44e59446d0b9bb805c56.jpg" title="" alt="blahblah" border="0" height="90" width="728">`

I want to get the "blahblah" from above image tag.

Answer (score 4):

[Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

<s>Untested</s> [Demo](https://eval.in/195329)

```
$string = '<img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/a61df59863ed44e59446d0b9bb805c56.jpg" title="" alt="blahblah" border="0" height="90" width="728">';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($string);
$anchor = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);
echo $anchor->getAttribute('alt');
```

Comment: Please I need regex instead of this.

Comment: @Michael Why does it have to be a regex?

Comment: @JohnConde sure man no prob, anyway i always prefer to go this route

Comment: I just need it anyway, please.